# Is this possible to use LWUIT in sun java wireless toolkit 2.5.2 midp2.0?

Tags: java-me

please let me know whether it is possible or not? if yes give me the procedure to setup and run the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use LWUIT with java wireless toolkit. You can use LWUIT 1.4 jar file. If you want to latest source code, checkout [here...](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/source/browse/lwuit/) Use netbeans, build the LWUIT project and get latest LWUIT jar file. Netbeans already having sun java wireless toolkit 2.5.2. In eclipse you need to add the plugin for this. and use the LWUIT jar file for your application.

Comment: where i put the lwuit jar file in sun java wireless toolkit 2.5.2. I didn't use any IDE...

Answer (score 0):

LWUIT is a framework.That builds upon j2me.Better u refer the oracle site for further information.

Comment: Ya we can use LWUIT in j2me wirless toolkt.Better u use IDE like Eclipse or netbeans.